# Xamarin iOS Failed to Install

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I am a Window user so to work with Xamarin I borrowed a Mac. After installing Xamarin and it's components on Mac I am able to connect it with my windows machine but when I run the debugger for running the application I get following error

[image: Issue]

Please help.

NOTE - Already looked into [Xamarin Forms iOS Deploy with simulator Failed To Install ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969145/xamarin-forms-ios-deploy-with-simulator-failed-to-install-error) but it didn't help.

Android is working fine.

TIA

Comment: I started with Xamarin a couple of weeks ago, and just started getting this error today.  Truly painful.

Comment: @BrainSlug83: Did below solutions helped. If yes please upvote the right one so that other people find it useful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Got it working.

1. In Windows go to Tools => Options => Xamarin => iOS Settings => Uncheck Remote Simulator
2. Run the application in debug mode, you will see the emulator in the Mac(A big emulator press CTRL+3 to get it normal).
3. If 2nd step fails go for release mode and then again for debug mode.
4. Now again check the Remote Emulator option under xamarin

Run the application and it worked.

I hope it helps for other devs who are searching for the similar issue.

Comment: I tried the same process as above but I get the same result. The emulator on the Mac works fine but when I check "Remote Simulator" I get the same "Failed to install ..." error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you run in debug mode?

Comment: Emulator works again on windows - great. But Breakpoints are still not hit. :-(

Comment: Try to run the project in Debug mode instead of Release

Comment: I get an error "error MT0069: The app directory [path-on-imac] does not exist". Any ideas  why?

Answer (score 5):

I just had this exact problem after updating to the latest version of Xamarin and Xcode (from 8.0 to 8.1) without also updating my Xamarin Remote Simulator.

I was using:

https://dl.xamarin.com/xamarin-simulator/Xamarin.Simulator.Installer.0.10.0.6.msi

Xamarin separately released a new version of the Remote Simulator to support Xcode 8.1:

https://releases.xamarin.com/preview-ios-simulator-for-windows-update-6/
https://dl.xamarin.com/xamarin-simulator/Xamarin.Simulator.Installer.0.10.1.1.msi

When I installed it and hit Debug, the Visual Studio log window showed it installing an updated Remote Simulator Server to the Mac, and then my app deployed and debugged properly.

For future visitors to this page, make sure the version of Xamarin Remote Simulator you're using also matches the versions of Xamarin and Xcode used.

Xamarin posts about these releases as they become available, here:

https://releases.xamarin.com

Comment: Phew, did not think that the win-simulator does not check for updates... thanks!